"TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'QVariant' and 'int'" when automatically updating with PyQGIS
Using the Python Console I would like to update multiple columns at once that run the same function. I have a list of column names and a function, there is a for loop that should iterate through the list updating the columns.
Within the "value_fields" are some NULL values, that might be causing the problem, isn't it?
from qgis.core import QgsProject, QgsField, edit
from PyQt5.QtCore import QVariant

# Function to update colour columns based on the ratio
def update_colour_columns(layer, value_fields, total_field):
    # Generate colour field names by taking the first two characters after the last underscore
    colour_fields = []
    for field in value_fields:
        parts = field.split('_')
        if len(parts) > 1:
            colour_fields.append(f"Farbe_{parts[-1][:2]}")
        else:
            print(f"Skipping invalid field name: {field}")
    
    # Ensure the colour_fields list matches value_fields length
    if len(value_fields) != len(colour_fields):
        print(f"Mismatch between value_fields and colour_fields lengths: {len(value_fields)} vs {len(colour_fields)}")
        return
    
    # Check if colour fields exist, if not, add them
    existing_fields = layer.fields().names()
    new_fields = [QgsField(colour_field, QVariant.String) for colour_field in colour_fields if colour_field not in existing_fields]
    if new_fields:
        layer.dataProvider().addAttributes(new_fields)
        layer.updateFields()
    
    with edit(layer):
        for feature in layer.getFeatures():
            for value_field, colour_field in zip(value_fields, colour_fields):
                value = feature[value_field]
                total = feature[total_field]
                
                # Calculate the ratio
                ratio = round(value / total, 0)*100 if total != 0 else 0
                
                # Determine the colour based on the ratio
                if ratio > 120:
                    colour = '#980034'
                elif 100 <= ratio <= 120:
                    colour = '#fe3946'
                elif 90 <= ratio < 100:
                    colour = '#f7b827'
                elif 80 <= ratio < 90:
                    colour = '#fafe00'
                elif 70 <= ratio < 80:
                    colour = '#acff7e'
                elif 60 <= ratio < 70:
                    colour = '#0481f9'
                elif ratio < 60:
                    colour = '#047d04'
                else:
                    colour = 'light grey'
                
                # Update the feature
                feature[colour_field] = colour
                layer.updateFeature(feature)

# List of value fields
value_fields = [
    "in_one_06", "in_one_07", "in_one_08", "in_one_09",
    "in_one_10", "in_one_11", "in_one_12", "in_one_13",
    "in_one_14", "in_one_15", "in_one_16", "in_one_17",
    "in_one_18", "in_one_19", "in_one_20", "in_one_22",
    "in_one_02"
]

# Get the active layer
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('layer — colour_test')[0]

# Update the columns
update_colour_columns(layer, value_fields, 'Kapazität')

In this case, however, I still have an error:
# Python Console
# Use iface to access QGIS API interface or type '?' for more info
# Security warning: typing commands from an untrusted source can harm your computer
exec(Path('C:/Users/Name/AppData/Local/Temp/tmp_q249b1j').read_text())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS33~1.6\apps\Python312\Lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 71, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 34, in update_colour_columns
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'QVariant' and 'int'


Let's assume there is a point layer called 'Survey2' with its attribute table, see the image below:

With this trivial script:
from qgis.core import QgsProject

layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Survey2')[0]

total = layer.aggregate(QgsAggregateCalculator.Sum, "dtv")[0]

for feat in layer.getFeatures():
    value = feat["dtv"]
    ratio = round(value / total, 0) * 100 if total != 0 else 0

I could get a similar TypeError:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python312\Lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 7, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'QVariant' and 'float'

It is written float here due to the floating value of the total variable. If I change total = round(total) to be an integer, I could get the same TypeError:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python312\Lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 9, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'QVariant' and 'int'

As it was already noticed by @Bera, the problem was caused by the NULL-values presented in the field. Keep in mind, that they are of the PyQt5.QtCore.QVariant (qgis.PyQt.QtCore.QVariant) class type.
I would suggest either:

the try/except-block:
...       
try:
    ratio = round(value / total, 0) * 100 if total != 0 else 0
    if ratio > 120:
        colour = '#980034'
    elif 100 <= ratio <= 120:
        colour = '#fe3946'
    elif 90 <= ratio < 100:
        colour = '#f7b827'
    elif 80 <= ratio < 90:
        colour = '#fafe00'
    elif 70 <= ratio < 80:
        colour = '#acff7e'
    elif 60 <= ratio < 70:
        colour = '#0481f9'
    elif ratio < 60:
        colour = '#047d04'

except TypeError as e: 
    colour = 'light grey'


or the if/else-statement:
from qgis.core import NULL

...
if value != NULL:
    ratio = round(value / total, 0) * 100 if total != 0 else 0
    if ratio > 120:
        colour = '#980034'
    elif 100 <= ratio <= 120:
        colour = '#fe3946'
    elif 90 <= ratio < 100:
        colour = '#f7b827'
    elif 80 <= ratio < 90:
        colour = '#fafe00'
    elif 70 <= ratio < 80:
        colour = '#acff7e'
    elif 60 <= ratio < 70:
        colour = '#0481f9'
    elif ratio < 60:
        colour = '#047d04'

else:
    colour = 'light grey'


or since QGIS 3.28 the QgsVariantUtils class possesses a brilliant method isNull():

Returns true if the specified variant should be considered a NULL
value.
This method is more rigorous vs QVariant::isNull(), which will
return false on newer Qt versions for tests like QVariant( QDateTime() ).isNull().

from qgis.core import QgsVariantUtils

...
if not QgsVariantUtils.isNull(value):
    ratio = round(value / total, 0) * 100 if total != 0 else 0
    if ratio > 120:
        colour = '#980034'
    elif 100 <= ratio <= 120:
        colour = '#fe3946'
    elif 90 <= ratio < 100:
        colour = '#f7b827'
    elif 80 <= ratio < 90:
        colour = '#fafe00'
    elif 70 <= ratio < 80:
        colour = '#acff7e'
    elif 60 <= ratio < 70:
        colour = '#0481f9'
    elif ratio < 60:
        colour = '#047d04'

else:
    colour = 'light grey'




References:

QGIS 2.0: Dealing with Null values in pyqgis
Applying if-condition for NULL values in QGIS Python Console
Importing NULL in PyQGIS

